# MVC DefaultLockoutTimeSpan

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am working on a MVC Core 2 application and in my startup file I have these setting. What ever I try the DefaultLockoutTimeSpan is giving me 6 hours.

```
var lockoutOptions = new LockoutOptions()
            {
                AllowedForNewUsers = true,
                DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5
            };

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                    options.Lockout = lockoutOptions;
            })
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>() 
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Comment: Can you debug your code to add some more information to your question?

Comment: In testing if someone is locked out at noon then instead of them being locked out until 1pm the would be looked out until 6pm. I have checked, and the database and the pc both have the same time